# Reduce size of input with Bootstrap (CSS)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an HTML page in which I have different input fields, some with a unit and some without one.

When I add an input-group-addon class to the span, the width of the whole input gets totally messed up.

[image]

My question is, what can I do so that my input "Field 1" is aligned with the other two, both on the left and on the right ?

I tried adding a margin-left: 15px; on the field 1, but unfortunately, this gives this ouput, which is not looking great.

[image]

I am using Bootstrap for the fields. Thanks.

Here is the code for the HTML:

```css
.inputUnite {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <div class="composant">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="control-label">
          <label for="input_A2B"><span class="symbol-required">*</span><span>Field 1</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 input-group">
        <input class="form-control inputUnite" aria-invalid="false" required="required" data-format="numeric" maxlength="6" id="input_A2B" name="a2b.value" value="" data-spinnertabindex="null" tabindex="null">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="unit_A2B">cm</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="composant">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="control-label">
          <label for="input_T5ZA2"><span class="symbol-required">*</span><span>Field 2</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control" aria-invalid="false" required="required" data-format="alphanumerique" maxlength="2" id="input_T5ZA2" name="T5ZA2.value" value="" data-spinnertabindex="null" tabindex="null">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="composant">
    <div class="form-group row has-error">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="control-label">
          <label for="textarea_A3D"><span class="symbol-required">*</span><span>Field 3</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea class="form-control has-error" aria-invalid="true" required="required" data-format="alphabetique" maxlength="558" id="textarea_A3D" name="A3D.value" data-spinnertabindex="null" tabindex="null"></textarea>
        <p class="letter-count" aria-live="polite"><span>558</span> caractères restants</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show us your code.. so i can show it

Comment: can you post the code of the all page - the three input fileds

Answer (score 0):

Adding another class inside the div col-md-6 was the reason it messed up.
So what I did was to separate the code in two different , as follows:

```
<div>
        <div class="composant">
                <div class="form-group row has-error">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="control-label">
                            <label for="input_A2B">
                                <!-- caractère obligatoire -->
                                <span class="symbol-required">*</span>
                                <span>Field 1</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" aria-invalid="true" required="required" data-format="numeric" maxlength="6" id="input_A2B" name="a2b.value" value="" data-spinnertabindex="null" tabindex="null">       
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="unité_A2B">cm</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you wont is to margin 15px to the left, move the class `inputUnite` (the one you defined), from the `form-control` div to the parent div, the `input-group`. 
That will apply the changes to the all input group, the input and the 'cm' span.

For that style to apply only on the `input-group`, you need to wrap the `col-md-6` div with a `row` div' and seperate the all the outher input fileds to another `row` div.

In the code below I added a second input field so we could see the relative position, each input is in is own `row` div.

```
<div>
<div class="composant">
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="control-label">
                    <label for="input_A2B">
                        <span class="symbol-required">*</span>
                        <span>Field 1</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 inputUnite input-group">
                <input class="form-control" aria-invalid="false" required="required" data-format="numeric" maxlength="6" id="input_A2B" name="a2b.value"
                    value="" data-spinnertabindex="null" tabindex="null">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="unit_A2B">cm</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="control-label">
                    <label for="input_A2C">
                        <span class="symbol-required">*</span>
                        <span>Field 2</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control" id="input_A2C" aria-invalid="false" required="required" data-format="numeric">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdmMdR?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your `input-group` from the `.col-md-6` and make an another div inside `.col-md-6` with class `input-group` for better understanding of code.

Also use `.container` or `.container-fluid` class outside of `.row`...

No need to use `.inputUnite` class here...

***Stack Snippet***

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="composant">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="control-label">
          <label for="input_A2B"><span class="symbol-required">*</span><span>Field 1</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control inputUnite" aria-invalid="false" required="required" data-format="numeric" maxlength="6" id="input_A2B" name="a2b.value" value="" data-spinnertabindex="null" tabindex="null">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="unit_A2B">cm</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="composant">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="control-label">
          <label for="input_T5ZA2"><span class="symbol-required">*</span><span>Field 2</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input class="form-control" aria-invalid="false" required="required" data-format="alphanumerique" maxlength="2" id="input_T5ZA2" name="T5ZA2.value" value="" data-spinnertabindex="null" tabindex="null">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="composant">
    <div class="form-group row has-error">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="control-label">
          <label for="textarea_A3D"><span class="symbol-required">*</span><span>Field 3</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea class="form-control has-error" aria-invalid="true" required="required" data-format="alphabetique" maxlength="558" id="textarea_A3D" name="A3D.value" data-spinnertabindex="null" tabindex="null"></textarea>
        <p class="letter-count" aria-live="polite"><span>558</span> caractères restants</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```